# Unknown signer error in Multisig account transaction

Tags: spl-token, multisig, signer

```
let wallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(key));
console.log("wallet", await wallet.publicKey.toBase58());
// 3 keypairs
const pk1 = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(key1));
console.log("wallet 1", pk1.publicKey.toBase58());
const pk2 = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(key2));
console.log("wallet 2", pk2.publicKey.toBase58());
const pk3 = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(key3));
console.log("wallet 3", pk3.publicKey.toBase58());

const multisigKey = Keypair.generate();
console.log("mullll", multisigKey.publicKey.toBase58());

const hi = await createMultisig(
  connection,
  pk1,
  [pk1.publicKey, pk2.publicKey, pk3.publicKey],
  2,
  multisigKey
);
console.log("multi sig", hi.toBase58());

const transaction = new Transaction().add(
  SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
    toPubkey: hi,
    lamports: 15651157,
  })
);

// Sign and send the transaction
const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [
  wallet,
]);
console.log(`Transaction ${signature} confirmed`);

const transaction2 = new Transaction().add(
  SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: hi,
    toPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
    lamports: 15655,
  })
);

transaction2.recentBlockhash = (
  await connection.getLatestBlockhash()
).blockhash;

transaction2.feePayer = pk2.publicKey;
transaction2.partialSign([pk1, pk3]);
transaction2.sign(pk2);
console.log(await transaction2.verifySignatures());
// Sign and send the transaction
const sign = await connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction2.serialize());
await connection.confirmTransaction(sign, "confirmed");
// const sign = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [
//   pk1,
//   pk2,
// ]);
console.log(`Transaction ${sign} confirmed`);
```

and this is what i get in my console

```
wallet 5oMMY9cDEp36zWqYqoKYoW2wY1eheWk5wvS8Gb636BKC
wallet 1 8Mh5T8mH43gEoAaAo27mEiB6g7w4cEmP8Gaao1iUjPnA
wallet 2 AGdXuBtXLZ4nT7JHsTSTJc4a8sqDUH9JGLSpu5XRwFx1
wallet 3 4XrYJtuXa75f4wVJbGExSwCDuLJMJU46yEkgc9PNeRR5
mullll A9gqQzKXSzEZmjA18dKrni6NXEriiZSo1x2oh6dz5yn3
multi sig A9gqQzKXSzEZmjA18dKrni6NXEriiZSo1x2oh6dz5yn3
Transaction 2qhjutP2CTrX61BtujJya7RiKanwJWjyBuFpXCU52KqCV85WjP3o9d6Nugex8doQRErMTZcy83rzduT8NSHg5FdJ confirmed
/home/dev-ice/bitoku/test/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1879
      throw new Error(`unknown signer: ${pubkey.toString()}`);
            ^

Error: unknown signer: 8Mh5T8mH43gEoAaAo27mEiB6g7w4cEmP8Gaao1iUjPnA
    at Transaction._addSignature (/home/dev-ice/bitoku/test/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1879:13)
    at /home/dev-ice/bitoku/test/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1853:12
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Transaction._partialSign (/home/dev-ice/bitoku/test/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1850:13)
    at Transaction.partialSign (/home/dev-ice/bitoku/test/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1841:10)
```

i tried using all of them as signer but the same error

Update :

i added this extra code

```
const accountMeta1 = {
  pubkey: pk1.publicKey,
  isSigner: true,
  isWritable: false,
};
const accountMeta2 = {
  pubkey: pk2.publicKey,
  isSigner: true,
  isWritable: false,
};
const accountMeta3 = {
  pubkey: pk3.publicKey,
  isSigner: true,
  isWritable: false,
};
await transaction2.instructions[0].keys.push(accountMeta1);
await transaction2.instructions[0].keys.push(accountMeta2);
await transaction2.instructions[0].keys.push(accountMeta3);
```

and now i'm getting this error

```
Error: Signature verification failed
    at Transaction.serialize (/home/dev-ice/bitoku/test/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1933:13)
```

Comment: Did you try partialSign with all the 3 keypairs and not using sign. I mean in this way
transaction2.partialSign([pk1,pk2 ,pk3]) and remove transaction2.sign

Comment: tried it, but the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this multiSig function works for spl token like here

```
let wallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(key));
console.log("wallet", await wallet.publicKey.toBase58());
// 3 keypairs
const pk1 = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(key1));
// console.log("wallet 1", pk1.publicKey.toBase58());
const pk2 = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(key2));
// console.log("wallet 2", pk2.publicKey.toBase58());
const pk3 = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(key3));
// console.log("wallet 3", pk3.publicKey.toBase58());

const multisigKey = Keypair.generate();
// console.log("mullll", multisigKey.publicKey.toBase58());

const hi = await createMultisig(
  connection,
  wallet,
  [pk1.publicKey, pk2.publicKey, pk3.publicKey],
  2,
  multisigKey
);

const mint = await createMint(
  connection,
  wallet,
  wallet.publicKey,
  wallet.publicKey,
  2
);
console.log("mint", mint.toBase58());

const acc1 = await createAccount(
  connection,
  wallet,
  mint,
  hi,
  Keypair.generate()
);

console.log("acc 1", acc1.toBase58());

const acc2 = await createAccount(
  connection,
  wallet,
  mint,
  hi,
  Keypair.generate()
);

console.log("acc2", acc2.toBase58());

const ui = await mintTo(connection, wallet, mint, acc1, wallet, 1000);

console.log("mint to", ui);
const transf = await transfer(connection, wallet, acc1, acc2, hi, 10, [
  pk1,
  pk2,
  pk3,
]);

console.log(transf);
```

I don't know if it works for non spl-tokens.

Comment: The SPL token multisig only works for SPL tokens, and not for SOL. It does work for wrapped SOL accounts, however. In general, I'd recommend using a more generic multisig over the SPL-token version